# Lenono vibe k5 5.0 device Service killed issue when i remove application from task manager

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have a service which is running for getting GPS location .
My service work on all other devices when i force fully killed the app but in lenovo mobile it killed service also.

**service**

```
<service
      android:name="com.LogngRunningService"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:exported="true" />
```

**LogngRunningService**

```
public class LogngRunningService extends Service {


    Context context;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        context = this;

        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        setRepeatingTask();//here i am calling method to get GPS location
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
        super.onRebind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTrimMemory(int level) {
        super.onTrimMemory(level);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
    }

    public LogngRunningService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


}
```

can somebody please help me to figure out this issue

Comment: also getting same in lenovo vibe k5 device